# Youtube embed code does not work in html for firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, youtube, embed

I'm brand new to HTML and trying to develop some basic skills and build a knowledge base by writing example pages.  I copy and paste the default youtube embed code and paste it in my code.  If I use the old code, I get a big white box.  The new code yields a box containing dialog which states that firefox could not find the page.  Chrome loads the object with no issues.  Here is the code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OIDnYMODZAQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: When I reloaded the page by clicking a link I had to it on another, the video was embedded properly; however, simply refreshing the page did not do the job.Strange, but no issues now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using http instead of https

```
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OIDnYMODZAQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```